# ¿Como enviar varios registros a través de un $http.post?

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, angularjs, base-de-datos

quiero guardar en la base de datos varios registros una vez presione un botón, para hacer eso, utilizo un función en mi controlador y a través de un $http.post envió el registro, el problema que tengo es que solo puedo enviar un solo registro, para enviar varios tengo que hacer varios $http.post y no creo que eso sea lo mejor.

Función en el controllador de Laravel:

```
public function funcionesDeUsuario(Request $request){
    $funcionesDeUsuario= new FuncionesDeUsuario();
    $funcionesDeUsuario->funcion= $request->funcion;
    $funcionesDeUsuario->user_id    = $request->user_id;
    $funcionesDeUsuario->detalles= $request->detalles;

    $funcionesDeUsuario->save();
}
```

Función que envía los datos a la base de datos, angular javascript:

```
$scope.enviarFunciones= function(){
  $http.post("/funcionesDeUsuario", {indicadorP: $scope.indicadorEstudiantes, user_id: userID, detalles: 'Estudiante'});
    $http.post("/funcionesDeUsuario", {funcion: $scope.indicadorDocente, user_id: userID, detalles: 'Docentes'});
    $http.post("/funcionesDeUsuario", {funcion: $scope.indicadorContenido, user_id: userID, detalles: 'Contenidos'});
    $http.post("/funcionesDeUsuario", {funcion: $scope.indicadorMetodologias, user_id: userID, detalles: 'Metologías'});

}
```

Si ven mi problema? es un poco tedioso hacer eso, disculpen mi código estoy aprendiendo y me falta mejorar muchas cosas.

gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Por el lado laravel deberias ser capaz de recibir un Array de nuevos usuarios.

Deberias enviar algo asi:

Angularjs

```
var datos = {
    usuarios = [
        {
            indicadorP: $scope.indicadorEstudiantes, 
            user_id: userID, 
            detalles: 'Estudiante'
        },
        ....
    ];
}
$http.post("/funcionesDeUsuario", datos);
```

Y en laravel

```
for ($request->usuarios as &$usuario) {
    $funcionesDeUsuario= new FuncionesDeUsuario();
    $funcionesDeUsuario->funcion= $usuario->funcion;
    $funcionesDeUsuario->user_id    = $usuario->user_id;
    $funcionesDeUsuario->detalles= $usuario->detalles;
    $funcionesDeUsuario->save();
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, entonces en la función controllador de laravel, el parámetro es un array? no me queda claro lo del ciclo for, es decir; mi función FuncionesDeUsuario() queda tal cual, pero como hago para emplear el ciclo for?

Comment: le envias un objeto que contiene un array de todos los usuarios que estas creando @Talked

Comment: entiendo, el problema que tengo es que no logro encontrar una sintaxis correcta para hacerlo.

Comment: no deberia cambiar a lo que te deje como respuesta @Talked